# NSMutableDictionary setObject:forKey (ios 6 without ARC) results in NULL

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

The following code was working prior to upgrading to iOS 6.  It works in the 5.1 iPhone simulator as well, but fails with 6.0 simulator and device.

Trying to setObject:forKey in a loop to an NSMutableDictionary.  Have tried adding in the loop (as the following code shows) and also tried by initializing with arrays for objects and keys which results in the same failure.  Another strange bit of information is that sometimes it works but fails most of the time.  The object being added is a UILocalNotification and the key is an object that represents a WeekDay (more than a simple string).  The output of running is shown below.  The UILocalNotifications and keys are clearly not NULL but the added pair in the MutableDictionary has NULL for some of the objects most of the time.  Mostly it's the last added day (key) whose object is null.  I'm completely at a loss as to how this breaking, thanks in advance for any help!

copy method for WeekDay (NSCopying Protocol):

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    WeekDay * copy = [[WeekDay alloc] initWithDay:self.day];
    return copy;
}
```

code snippet using setObject:forKey:

```
NSMutableDictionary * newAlarmsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSArray * theDayKeys = [[_daysEnabledDict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

NSMutableArray * tempNotifyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UILocalNotification * theAlarm = nil;
WeekDay * theWeekDay = nil;

for (int i=0; i < [theDayKeys count]; i++) {

    if ([[_daysEnabledDict objectForKey:[theDayKeys objectAtIndex:i]] boolValue] == TRUE) {

        theWeekDay = [theDayKeys objectAtIndex:i];

        NSDate * now = [NSDate date];

... deleted lines setting up fire date for UILocalNotification, not significant to problem ...

        theAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        theAlarm.fireDate = itemDate;
        theAlarm.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
        theAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
        theAlarm.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        theAlarm.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

        [newAlarmsDictionary setObject:theAlarm forKey:theWeekDay];
        [tempNotifyArray addObject:theAlarm];
        [theAlarm release];
        }
    }
}
NSLog(@"--Debug: tempNotifyArray---- %@ -------------", tempNotifyArray);
NSLog(@"--Debug: newAlarmsDictionary ====== %@ =============", newAlarmsDictionary);
```

Here is the output of the two NSlog statements at the end of the code snippet.  This particular run adds 4 notifications, for days wed thru sat.  The 'alarms' put into the tempNotifyArray are valid but when added to the dictionary (one in this case) is null.

```
2012-11-26 11:07:01.087 MedTrack[9728:11303] --Debug: tempNotifyArray---- (

"<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x7277940>{fire date = Wednesday, November 28, 2012, 11:06:00 AM Eastern Standard Time, time zone = America/Toronto (EST) offset -18000, repeat interval = NSWeekCalendarUnit, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Wednesday, November 28, 2012, 11:06:00 AM Eastern Standard Time, user info = {\n    Temp = Fred;\n}}",


"<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x8883280>{fire date = Thursday, November 29, 2012, 11:06:00 AM Eastern Standard Time, time zone = America/Toronto (EST) offset -18000, repeat interval = NSWeekCalendarUnit, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Thursday, November 29, 2012, 11:06:00 AM Eastern Standard Time, user info = {\n    Temp = Fred;\n}}",


"<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x75c6590>{fire date = Friday, November 30, 2012, 11:06:00 AM Eastern Standard Time, time zone = America/Toronto (EST) offset -18000, repeat interval = NSWeekCalendarUnit, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Friday, November 30, 2012, 11:06:00 AM Eastern Standard Time, user info = {\n    Temp = Fred;\n}}",


"<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x75c83e0>{fire date = Saturday, December 1, 2012, 11:06:00 AM Eastern Standard Time, time zone = America/Toronto (EST) offset -18000, repeat interval = NSWeekCalendarUnit, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Saturday, December 1, 2012, 11:06:00 AM Eastern Standard Time, user info = {\n    Temp = Fred;\n}}"
```

) -------------

```
2012-11-26 11:07:01.097 MedTrack[9728:11303] --Debug: newAlarmsDictionary ====== {


"[WeekDay] 6 (Sat)" = (null);


"[WeekDay] 3 (Wed)" = "<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x7277940>{fire date = Wednesday, November 28, 2012, 11:06:00 AM Eastern Standard Time, time zone = America/Toronto (EST) offset -18000, repeat interval = NSWeekCalendarUnit, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Wednesday, November 28, 2012, 11:06:00 AM Eastern Standard Time, user info = {\n    Temp = Fred;\n}}";


"[WeekDay] 4 (Thu)" = "<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x8883280>{fire date = Thursday, November 29, 2012, 11:06:00 AM Eastern Standard Time, time zone = America/Toronto (EST) offset -18000, repeat interval = NSWeekCalendarUnit, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Thursday, November 29, 2012, 11:06:00 AM Eastern Standard Time, user info = {\n    Temp = Fred;\n}}";


"[WeekDay] 5 (Fri)" = "<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x75c6590>{fire date = Friday, November 30, 2012, 11:06:00 AM Eastern Standard Time, time zone = America/Toronto (EST) offset -18000, repeat interval = NSWeekCalendarUnit, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Friday, November 30, 2012, 11:06:00 AM Eastern Standard Time, user info = {\n    Temp = Fred;\n}}";
```

Comment: How are you implementing your `WeekDay`'s `copy` method?

Comment: It's recommended to never create a variable without initialization, at least initialization to nil, otherwise it will point to memory garbage. UILocalNotification * theAlarm = nil;
WeekDay * theWeekDay = nil;

Comment: Does the ARC complain about the [theAlarm release] line?

Comment: @mashdup: Bejan is not using ARC, see the title.

Comment: updated based on @deanWombourne's comments, added WeekDay's copy method (NSCopying protocol).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that you implement `-copyWithZone:`, but you fail to implement `-isEqual:`. Without knowing the full structure of your object, I cannot answer how that should be implemented, but here's a good basis:

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)otherObject;
{
    if ([otherObject isKindOfClass:[self class]]) {
        WeekDay *otherWeekDay= (WeekDay *)otherObject;
        if (self.day != [otherWeekDay day]) return NO;
        if (self.name != [otherWeekDay name]) return NO;
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger) hash;
{
    return self.day ^ [self.name hash];
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that i should override isEqual to return yes if the variables in the object are the same even though the -hash is different?  Documentation says that's a no-no.

Comment: No, you must also implement `-hash`, just like you would in Java.

Comment: Worked.  So, if i understand correctly, due to optimization in the NSMutableDictionary, the objects i was using as keys which contained basic types and strings were colliding in a test for equality?  Here's the code i added to WeekDay, the object i am using as a key...

Comment: Whoops, added the code to your answer that i used to fix.  I think 'instancetype' is only available when using the clang switch which i don't have enabled.

Comment: @BejanShemirani no worries mate. The reason that `-isEqual:` is required is because `NSDictionary` copies it's keys. If it didn't check `-isEqual:`, then there could be no way that another object could have the same reference as the object that you just copied. Hash is just another way of testing equality, and is mostly used for collection storage.